# Fine uploader : setting blobProperties name to function

Tags: fine-uploader

I have something like below code

```
blobProperties: {
   name: function (id) {
      return "blobname";
   }
}
```

But its not working it is giving following exception: **onGetBlobName(...).then is not a function.**

When I set name to 'filename' instead of function it is working.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-azure.html#blobProperties.name) is incorrect in this case. It says:

> If the value is a function it may return one of a qq.Promise or a String.

But, looking at [the code](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/master/client/js/azure/uploader.basic.js#L98), if a function is returned, that function is executed and not wrapped in a new function that returns a `Promise`. In other words, if your function does not return a `Promise`, then you will see the error described in your question since code elsewhere in Fine Uploader Azure expects blob name determination to be "thenable".

So, to workaround this issue, simply return a `Promise` in your `blobProperties.name` function, and `resolve` it with the blob name. Please also open up a pull request with a fix for this issue. I'll be happy to guide you through contributing a fix.

Comment: yes, it works with following code -                 name: function (id) {                  
                    return new Promise(function (resolve) {                        
                        resolve("blobname");
                    });
                }

Thanks

Comment: Please also open up a pull request with a fix for this issue. I'll be happy to guide you through contributing a fix.